# WatchQuery doesn't update from subscription

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Why doesn't subscription update apollo store/cache to then trigger watchQuery observable? What would usage look like with raw api if can't depend on side effects like described in question?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is that you're then expected to manually update the denormolized cache of theirs, and even then are more likely to find yourself using subscribeToMore method on watchedQuery that I can't find not using react api if not using polling avoiding the complexity (in their own words).